# python: perform a generic multi dimensional loop

Tags: python

Python:

How to efficiency execute a multidimensional loop, when the number of indexes to loop is dynamic.

Assume an array var_size containing the size of each variable

```
var_size = [ 3, 4, 5 ]
```

and a function 'loop' which will call 'f(current_state)' for each point.

```
  def f(state): print state
  loop(var_size, f)
```

This call would call *f* in the following order:

```
 f( [ 0, 0, 0])
 f( [ 0, 0, 1])
 f( [ 0, 0, 2])
 f( [ 0, 1, 0])
 etc....
```

Comment: I think you can manage this with `itertools.product` -- `itertools.starmap` might also be useful.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with `itertools.product`:

```
>>> print list(itertools.product(*(range(x) for x in reversed([3,4,5]))))
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 0), (0, 2, 1), (0, 2, 2), (0, 3, 0), (0, 3, 1), (0, 3, 2), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 2), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 2, 0), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2), (1, 3, 0), (1, 3, 1), (1, 3, 2), (2, 0, 0), (2, 0, 1), (2, 0, 2), (2, 1, 0), (2, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (2, 2, 0), (2, 2, 1), (2, 2, 2), (2, 3, 0), (2, 3, 1), (2, 3, 2), (3, 0, 0), (3, 0, 1), (3, 0, 2), (3, 1, 0), (3, 1, 1), (3, 1, 2), (3, 2, 0), (3, 2, 1), (3, 2, 2), (3, 3, 0), (3, 3, 1), (3, 3, 2), (4, 0, 0), (4, 0, 1), (4, 0, 2), (4, 1, 0), (4, 1, 1), (4, 1, 2), (4, 2, 0), (4, 2, 1), (4, 2, 2), (4, 3, 0), (4, 3, 1), (4, 3, 2)]
```

Note that I'm generating `tuple`s instead of `list`s, but that's easy to fix if you really need to.

So, to me it looks like you want:

```
map(f,itertools.product(*map(range,reversed(var_size))))
```

Comment: @user9876 -- because it appears that OP wants the `range(3)` to be in the fast loop.

Answer (score 0):

Make a list initialized to 0s, as many entries as are in var_size. We treat this list as a list of 'tumblers' - we increment the last one in the list until it overflows its limit (aka var_size at the same point into the list). If so, we set it to 0, go one left and repeat the increment/overflow check until we either do not overflow (reset the 'which tumbler are we looking at' variable back to the last and continue) or overflow all entries of the list (we're done, we looped all the way around), then perform the next call.

I don't know if this is optimal or pythonic, but it is O(n).

Answer (score 0):

This code does the job - And it has the advantage of not creating the list. However, it not that elegant....

Any ideas on how to get this better?

```
def loop(var_size, f):
    nb = len(var_size)
    state = [0]*nb
    ok = True
    while ok:
        f(state)
        for i in range(nb-1, -1, -1):
            state[i] = state[i]+1
            if state[i] < var_size[i]:
                break
            else:
                if i == 0:
                    ok = False
                    break
                else:
                    state[i] = 0

var_size = [3,4,5]  
def f(state): 
    print state

loop(var_size, f)
```